# Error Message when enabling Livepatch : cannot parse /etc/fstab: expected between 3 and 6 fields, found 8

Tags: fstab, canonical-livepatch

```
Ubuntu 18.04
4.15.0-66-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When enabling Livepatch from Canonical Livepatch Service, I followed the instructions and pasted the commands in terminal:

```
sudo snap install canonical-livepatch
```

that was OK

```
sudo canonical-livepatch enable ###my key number###
```

Returned:

```
system_key.go:120: cannot determine nfs usage in generateSystemKey: cannot parse /etc/fstab: expected between 3 and 6 fields, found 8
```

Any easy directions on that?

Comment: Already solved thanks to Manfred: https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+question/688150